# exc_bad_access only iOS Version < 9 - textfield deallocated (

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, exc-bad-access

My app doesn't work for Versions older than iOS 9.x

The APP throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception at a textField. The textField is in a tableView.
I enabled Zombie Objects: "[_UILabelLayer opacity]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x81018770"

It doesn't appear at the beginning. It only crashs when I click on the tableView cells or when my 30 seconds timer refreshs the UI. (I disabled the timer, but there were no changes)

I tried dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) and semaphores. I got no positive effects.

I check, whether the objects is nil, but it isn't:

```
if self.textField != nil {
                if let textFieldNotNil = self.textField {

                    // textField.removeFromSuperview()  
                    print("The Textfield \(textFieldNotNil.text)")
                    print("The Textfield \(textFieldNotNil)")

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    textFieldNotNil.text = strValue
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I use textField.removeFromSuperview() the app works again, but then there is no value inside the textfield. (That is clear, I removed it from the superview -.-)

Can I check, if my textfield is allocated? I can't find anything.
Have someone any other ideas?

EDIT

> Sending a message to a nil would not cause your app to crash, I think.

I think this, too. My textfield isn't nil, too. But it crashs, this is the strange thing.

> Do you have a StackTrace?

If u mean with StackTrace a do { try ... } catch {}-construct. No, I haven't. I searched for an example to surround a textfield.text = ".." with do/try/catch, but I can't find.

> When does it crash? When you access textFieldNotNil.text? 
>   This is the strange thing. It crashs in the line: textFieldNotNil.text = strValue

The error is that textFieldNotNil is deallocated. textFieldNotNil is called, when the user clicks on a tableViewCell or every 30 seconds.

> Does this crash happen when you replace textFieldNotNil.text = strValue with [textFieldNotNil setText:strValue]?

Is it objectiv C? The compiler is bitching "Expected "," separator

> You could also try textFieldNotNil.stringValue = strValue
>   I can't. My textFieldNotNil hasn't an attribute like stringValue. What's that?
>
> Is self.textField declared weak?

Yes, it is. @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField?

> Are you on a background thread when you call dispatch_async?
>   I don't know... I don't understand the stacktrace output so much.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x38475f, 0x058f8e86 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGKILL
frame #0: 0x058f8e86 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10
frame #1: 0x058f5db9 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kill$UNIX2003 + 32
frame #2: 0x01f4829d CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1069
frame #3: 0x01f47e4e CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 14
frame #4: 0x034904e8 UIKit`-[UIView(Rendering) alpha] + 42
frame #5: 0x1287e70a UIKit`-[UILabelAccessibility isAccessibilityElement] + 90
frame #6: 0x12aba330 MessageUIFramework`-[MessageUILabelAccessibility isAccessibilityElement] + 104
frame #7: 0x128942c9 UIKit`-[UITextFieldAccessibility _accessibilityCountAccessibleChildren:] + 211
frame #8: 0x1289449c UIKit`__42-[UITextFieldAccessibility _updateButtons]_block_invoke + 46
frame #9: 0x055bf5ea libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
frame #10: 0x055e1bef libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
frame #11: 0x055c52ef libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_after_timer_callback + 156
frame #12: 0x055e1bef libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
frame #13: 0x055d713a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 1063
frame #14: 0x055ce325 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 375
frame #15: 0x055c74ee libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 532
frame #16: 0x01f528ee CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
frame #17: 0x01f105f0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2256
frame #18: 0x01f0fa5b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
frame #19: 0x01f0f88b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #20: 0x061a52c9 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #21: 0x061a5106 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #22: 0x0340a0b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
* frame #23: 0x0031584c CocoSoftIOSBaseApp`main + 140 at   AppDelegate.swift:16
frame #24: 0x0560cac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

... a lot of more Threads

Comment: Sending a message to a `nil` would not cause your app to crash, I think. Do you have a StackTrace? When does it crash? When you access `textFieldNotNil.text`?

Comment: Does this crash happen when you replace `textFieldNotNil.text = strValue` with `[textFieldNotNil setText:strValue]`? You could also try `textFieldNotNil.stringValue = strValue`.

Comment: Is self.textField declared weak?  Are you on a background thread when you call `dispatch_async`?  (You can get a stack trace by typing "bt all" in the debug console when the app crashes.)

Comment: Oops. You're right, kuzdu. I thought about Objective-C ;-)

Comment: In Swift, sending messages to deallocated objects (nil) are invalid. This is the general logic lying underneath optionals and error safety.

Comment: okay okay, that is clear. but I try whether my textfield is nil and nevertheless the app try to set text and throw an error